# Minimal circuit to flash STM32F4 using STLINK

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash, stm32f4, st-link

I wonder if I need to put some circuit between STLINK and STM32F4 MCU to flash it or does it simply require to connect the wires 1:1 directly? I cannot find it in the datasheet.

Comment: You could have found this in the schematic of any of the discovery or nucleo boards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power, ground, and hook up the signal wires.  The processor takes care of making the flashing work.